# Postgres Query - Min and Max Values With Timestamps

Tags: postgresql, date-range, minmax

I'm trying to build a query that allows me to output a Minimum value with its timestamp and a Maximum value with its timestamp from a given database table. I also need to query the Avg but obviously without a timestamp. The query needs a date range between midnight and midnight of a day. Working towards building a daily report.

Comment: So you must have got somewhere, why not share that? Note - unless timestamps are guaranteed to be unique you may have two or more with the same max/min value

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ is a good place to get to know SQL

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.  Further clearly describe where you are having issues.